# How to give condition in xml file for showing different block in different pages

Tags: xml, magento-2.2.5, footer

How to give condition in xml file for showing different block in different pages. Like I place a block name "Footer Block" in default xml file, and I want different footer for different pages.

```
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_links_block">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_links_block</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

I want this that this footer only will show in home page and I want to different footer block for other pages. How I can do it in Magento 2.2.5

Thank You

Comment: Please clarify, by different pages you mean different type of pages or like different category pages/ different product pages?

Comment: I want to show footer in home page and different footer for other pages. And this footer section I have done by block. In default.xml file I fetch this block. So I want any condition that I can differentiate in xml file. How I can do this. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Hello @Vivek Kumar, is there any way to do this functionality? Sorry, that before I didn't clarify the question clearly. Please help, if is there any way to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got the solution.
I call the .phtml page into .xml file, like this.

**default.xml**

```
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <container name="footer-custom" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-custom">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="footer_upper" template="Magento_Theme::html/footer.phtml">                   
            </block>                
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
```

and then in .phtml file I place the condition and fetch the block there, like this.

**footer.phtml**

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cmsPage = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Cms\Model\Page');
    $cmsIdent = $cmsPage->getIdentifier();
?>

<?php
    if ($cmsIdent == 'home') {

        echo $block->getLayout()
           ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
           ->setBlockId('footer_links_block')
           ->toHtml();

    } else {

        echo $block->getLayout()
           ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
           ->setBlockId('footer_links_block_for_others')
           ->toHtml();

    }
?>
```

It works perfect for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to show it only for home page, then more appropriate solution will be to show them via cms_index_index.xml. In that way, you can manage everything via XML too including containers if you have to add them in near future.